# Remove website data of ios safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

I have created one web based game using JS. I have loaded resources to browser. After sometime i want to remove the loaded resource since i will be loading another set of resources. If i keep both set of images then browser will automatically get refresh by providing message "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded".

**Can anyone please tell me how to delete the resource which are saved in browser.**

I tried with some alternative method. If i refresh the page then resource will automatically removed. I used **`location.reload(true)`** code.

This works fine in desktop browser. But when i check in IPAD device safari browser page will be refreshed but resource size in browser are not deleted.

Any idea on this alternative method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better that you do the game with C # as it has a function to eliminate things that are not used to prevent your problem

Comment: Hi Jota,

I have already started with JS. Its little tough for me to shift language. Am using COcos2d-JS framework. 

Is there any method to solve the above issue. Anyway to delete loaded resources.